Are sporting competition rules a form of legal contract?
This is a mostly hypothetical question.
Consider this - a sports governing body organises a competition with a set of rules and a modest cash prize. The rules include a minor change (not a typo, an intended change to the way they've been run previously).
Most of the experienced competitors either don't read the rules or only give them a quick scan. A novice competitor reads the full set of rules.
The race is run, the veteran competitors all do very well and the novice comes in towards the back of the pack. The novice then re-reads the rules and realises that he's the first competitor that actually followed the letter of the law and all the preceding competitors should have been disqualified under new rules
He appeals to the organisers and they state (I'm paraphrasing) - "yes, you're correct but we're going to use the old set of rules for this one competition because we'll look stupid if we give you the first prize. the new rules will now apply from the next race forwards"
Is it legal for the organisers to behave like this? Is a set of rules with a cash prize not a form of legally binding contract? Or does the fact that this is just a sporting event mean they can do more-or less what they want?

I play in a bridge league. From time to time they make rule changes, but are generally conservative about punishing violators for a while after they take effect, to allow time for players to get used to them.

Maybe, it depends. Depending on how competitors signed up, there may be a legal agreement, but it may not require the organizer to disqualify the other competitors.
First of all, the best way to create an enforceable agreement is a written contract. Surely any sports league with considerable cash prizes will have participants sign a contract which will settle this question - it should clearly state the obligations of each party, as well as the mechanism to enforce violations of that contract. It's unlikely that the organizer will have agreed to terms like what you described - they may want to have the discretion to enforce the rules and apply punishments using their judgement in any given situation. There may even be a blanket disclaimer stating that the league has the right to make the final decision in the case of disputes related to rules enforcement.
If there isn't a written contract, then it would depend on what other kinds of documents the parties have signed, and what they have discussed. For example, in the case of The Satanita, one party in a yacht race was found liable to reimburse another for damages that occurred as a result of rule breaking. However, in this case, each party had agreed to follow a common ruleset which included that provision. Similar logic might apply to your case if the rules clearly state that the penalty for this must be disqualification without any room for judgement or discretion, and if all parties actually did agree to the rules.
Or, the league could argue that the rule which you think would disqualify the other competitors is obviously a mistake. In Hartog v Colin & Shields, one party made a pricing error in a contract, and the other party sought to enforce that mistaken pricing. Reasoning that the buyer must have realized that the seller had made a mistake in the pricing, the court ruled that there was no legal agreement. In your case, if "anyone with any knowledge of the [sport] must have realized that there was a mistake" with that rule, a similar argument could protect the league.

The question clearly states that it was "an intended change" to the rules. It sounds like they just didn't publicize it very well to people who had been playing under the old rules for many years.

@Barmar an intended change may have unintended consequences.

@DaleM Maybe, but this seems a far cry from "anyone must have realized that there was a mistake with that rule".

I think in team sports like soccer there is also the meta-rule that referee decisions overrule the written rules. So if a player does something that should be illegal but the referee declares its fine then it is fine in that instance. In the setting OP describes the referee might be critized afterwards for not applying the rules correctly but their decisions at the time of the competition would still stand.

@quarague Many games and sports have an appeals process, to handle referee mistakes.
